# Is it possible to change multiple values with the help of a single input slider?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is it possible to change multiple values with a single input slider? Because I tried many times but was unable to change different values. I want to change the value of 50,000 which is at the top of the slider, and the value of 250k which is in the unique view's container. When we move the slider forward the 50,000 value should be changed to 10,000 per step i.e. 50,000 then 60,000 then 70,000 and so on till 1,000,000. And the value of 250k should be changed to 50K per step i.e. 250k then 300k then 350k and so on till 5M. I have made this in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Codes are as follows-

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input"),
        number = document.querySelector(".slide-value"),
        uniqueViews = document.querySelector(".unique_views");

    input.addEventListener("input", () => {
        number.textContent = input.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
```

```css
.campaign {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 75%;
        background: gray;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-cards {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 32px;
        margin: 0 10%;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-cards .card {
        width: calc(25% - 30px);
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 50px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 35px 30px;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 130px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper .slide-value {
        font-size: 27px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #333;
        width: 70px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper input {
        width: 100%;
        appearance: none;
        height: 12px;
        background-color: #bdd6f9;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        appearance: none;
        height: 18px;
        width: 18px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 4px -1.5px #000;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper .min-max-value {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-matrics {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        gap: 20px;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-matrics .matrics-block {
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 10px 60px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="campaign">
        <h2 class="header custom-cursor">Making Influencer Campaign Simple</h2>
        <div class="details campaign-details">
            <div class="campaign-container">
                <div class="campaign-cards">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="title">
                            <h3>Traffic</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="campaign-slider">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <span class="slide-value">50,000</span>
                        <input type="range" min="50000" step="10000" max="1000000" value="50000" />
                        <div class="min-max-value">
                            <p>Min: ₹50,000</p>
                            <p>Max: ₹1,000,000</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="campaign-matrics">
                    <div class="matrics-block">
                        <div class="matrics-title">
                            <h4>Unique Views</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="matrics-value">
                            <h2 class="unique_views">250K</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="matrics-block">
                        <div class="matrics-title">
                            <h4>Cost per View</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="matrics-value">
                            <h2>0.2</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `I tried many times` show what you did, because what you've shown doesn't show you trying anyting

Comment: Firstly when I applied the same javascript for unique views but it changed 250k to 50,000 and started changing the values according to the budget value. Secondly, when I implemented the input type slider and made the position absolute and overlapped with the main slider the z-index caused problems

Comment: you haven't shown any of that in your code, have you? How do you expect help with code you haven't posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purpose to you to use jQuery.

First i placed span arround the value of your "unique_views" to get the value easier with selector.

Then i catch the event of slider change and get the value for "unique_views" and set the new value multiply by 5.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input"),
        number = document.querySelector(".slide-value"),
        uniqueViews = document.querySelector(".unique_views");

    input.addEventListener("input", () => {
        number.textContent = input.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
    
$('input').on("input change",(e)=>{
  // get the current value of "unique_views"
  var unique_views = $('.unique_views').find('span').text(); 
  // get the value of current slider and remove 3 last digit
  var current_slider_val = e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.value.length-3);
  // apply calculation for the new value of "unique_views"
  var new_unique_views = current_slider_val * 5;
  // set the new value of "unique_views"
  $('.unique_views span').text(new_unique_views);
});
```

```css
.campaign {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 75%;
        background: gray;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-cards {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 32px;
        margin: 0 10%;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-cards .card {
        width: calc(25% - 30px);
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 50px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 35px 30px;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 130px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper .slide-value {
        font-size: 27px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #333;
        width: 70px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper input {
        width: 100%;
        appearance: none;
        height: 12px;
        background-color: #bdd6f9;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        appearance: none;
        height: 18px;
        width: 18px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 4px -1.5px #000;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-slider .wrapper .min-max-value {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-matrics {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        gap: 20px;
    }

    .campaign .campaign-details .campaign-container .campaign-matrics .matrics-block {
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 10px 60px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 20px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="campaign">
        <h2 class="header custom-cursor">Making Influencer Campaign Simple</h2>
        <div class="details campaign-details">
            <div class="campaign-container">
                <div class="campaign-cards">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="title">
                            <h3>Traffic</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="campaign-slider">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <span class="slide-value">50,000</span>
                        <input type="range" min="50000" step="10000" max="1000000" value="50000" />
                        <div class="min-max-value">
                            <p>Min: ₹50,000</p>
                            <p>Max: ₹1,000,000</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="campaign-matrics">
                    <div class="matrics-block">
                        <div class="matrics-title">
                            <h4>Unique Views</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="matrics-value">
                            <h2 class="unique_views"><span>250</span>K</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="matrics-block">
                        <div class="matrics-title">
                            <h4>Cost per View</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="matrics-value">
                            <h2>0.2</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you replace "K" to "M"?

Comment: @shivanisrivastav just replace it in html